# Remove column from child gridview

Tags: c#, entity-framework, gridview, devexpress

The parent of this grid is **Project** while the child is **BOM**. I've manage to display child grid using the following code.

```
    private void gridView_MasterRowEmpty(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.MasterRowEmptyEventArgs e)
    {
        Project projects = (Project)gridView.GetRow(e.RowHandle);
        e.IsEmpty = projects.BOMs.Count == 0;
    }

    private void gridView_MasterRowGetRelationCount(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.MasterRowGetRelationCountEventArgs e)
    {
        e.RelationCount = 1;
    }

    private void gridView_MasterRowGetRelationName(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.MasterRowGetRelationNameEventArgs e)
    {
        e.RelationName = "BOMs";
    }

    private void gridView_MasterRowGetChildList(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.MasterRowGetChildListEventArgs e)
    {
        Project projects = (Project)gridView.GetRow(e.RowHandle);
        e.ChildList = new BindingSource(projects, "BOMs");
    }
```

However, the code is showing me all the columns. I would like to hide some columns from the child which is **BOM**.

The only way I found was to use something like below

```
 dataGridView1.Columns[index].Visible = false;
```

But where should I place the above code?

**Updated Code**

```
private void gridView_MasterRowExpanded(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.CustomMasterRowEventArgs e)
{
    GridView gridView = sender as GridView;
    GridView detailView = (GridView)gridView.GetDetailView(e.RowHandle, e.RelationIndex);
    detailView.Columns["Column Name"].Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fulfill your need you must handle the  `Grid_MasterRowExpanded` method in your GridControl :

```
private void Grid_MasterRowExpanded(System.Object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.CustomMasterRowEventArgs e)
{
    GridView view = sender;
    GridView detail = view.GetDetailView(e.RowHandle, e.RelationIndex);

    if (e.RowHandle == 0 | e.RowHandle == 1) {
        if (detail.Name == "BOM") {
            detail.Columns["Column Name"].Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your answer provided me a direction. However, I made some changes to it. Check the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, you can also do this at design-time, which is my favorite way to go.  Within the gridView designer, you need to make sure you create a gridView for the master and child.  Clicking "Retrieve Details" will do this.  It will also blow away any columns you have already created, along with the layout, but the easy way around this is to save the layout as an XML, click "Retrieve Details" and then re-load the XML.

Here is what your designer will look like after you do that:

[image]

From here, you can click on each gridView (the master and child separately) and customize each -- change column widths, hide columns, DELETE columns (the data is still there but impossible for the UI to add to the grid), rearrange columns, etc.

And the best part -- no code.

Comment: I've tried this but somehow when I click `Retrieve Details`, the child did not appear. Therefore, I tried using code instead. Maybe because I'm using EF.